# Loading Cakewalk TTS-1 synth presets into the Step Sequencer (Cakewalk)

Tags: synthesizer

Cakewalk's built-in synth TTS-1 gives the ability to record notes in the Step Sequencer.

[image: TTS1 - Step Sequencer]

However ,only the first preset in the active bank loads into the step sequencer automatically and the other presets don't .

How can one load all the presets in the active bank into the step sequencer?

Comment: not sure what you are asking here - one preset would be equivalent to one step sequence? What exactly are you trying to achieve?

Comment: so how does one switch between presets .... say from Sunvox to Piano1 ( in the above case)

Comment: what have you tried?